# I2C windows iot can't connect

Tags: i2c, windows-iot, c#

I'm trying to communicate between a Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IOT (build 14376 insiders) and a T-REX [Manual here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qodfg7lmtlrzjhz/T%27REX%20Controller%20Instruction%20Manual.pdf?dl=0) using I2C protocol. The thing is that it always crashes, so after some debugging I've found that it looks like it doesn't retrieve anything from the `DeviceInformation.FinAllAsync(..)` and that causes an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. It needs something I don't understand, maybe in the device capabilities or permissions, which the Microsoft tutorial [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/pinmappingsrpi2) doesn't mention.

```
var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x07);
settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;
var aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");
var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
int a = dis.Count; //is always equal to 0
```

Then I have a:

```
using (I2cDevice device = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id, settings)){...}
```

which fails with the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` mentioned before.

A second way I tried was using this code:

```
I2CDevice device;
var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x07);
settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;

var controller = await Windows.Devices.I2c.I2cController.GetDefaultAsync();
device = controller.GetDevice(settings);
```

which produces a `NullReferenceException` with the last line.